How do you flash foundation corners with copper termite barrier?
The issue is simple: I plan on retrofitting copper termite flashing at my sill to discourage termite intrusion.  But corners present a challenge, as I must cut the flashing to cover it.  I could try to solder the laps around the corners, but that seems impractical.
Are there any other solutions for providing a continuous barrier around foundation corners with copper flashing?
